# Need help correctly typing a function parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I created this function for embedding svg

```
export function svgLoader( path: string, targetObj: ElementRef ){
    let graphic = new XMLHttpRequest;

    graphic.open('GET', path, !0),
    graphic.send(),
    graphic.onload = (a)=>{
        let b = document.createElement('div');

        b.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden'),
        b.innerHTML = graphic.responseText,
        targetObj.insertBefore(b, targetObj.childNodes[0])
    }
}
```

The `targetObj` parameter is meant to take a DOM element referenced by a `@ViewChild` decorator.  The function works as expected, however I'm getting these errors in the console

> Property 'insertBefore' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.
>
> Property 'childNodes' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.

I originally had `targetObj:string` and it still worked, noticing the error is why I changed it to ElementRef.  Is there any particular way to handle this or should I just ignore the error?

**UPDATE**

Just thought I'd mention the function isn't defined inside of a component.  I import it in so I can use it on multiple components as needed.  This is How my component looks.

```
export class SomeClass implements OnInit {
     @ViewChild('svgDrop') SVGDrop: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(){
        svgLoader('../../../../assets/tld_sprite02.svg', this.SVGDrop.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

I noticed the responses were mainly based on working on things inside the class, I'm trying to figure out what to define the `targetObj` variable's type as so that it will take the element called with the `@ViewChild()` decorator.

Comment: Have you looked at Angulars Renderer2 class? https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2. It is the preferred method when accessing the DOM, because unlike ElementRef it prevents tight coupling between your app and rendering layers.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `nativeElement` property of your `ElementRef` object:

```
targetObj.nativeElement.insertBefore(b, targetObj.childNodes[0])
```

Because `insertBefore` is aactually a native DOM property, not a property of your `targetObj` itself.

Here is a full example from the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the interface for ElementRef. You will see it has a prop named `nativeElement` which houses the DOM node. So your code should be:
`targetObj.nativeElement.insertBefore(...)`.

Also note that `@ViewChild` will only resolve after certain lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the code snippet:

**app.component.html**

```
<p #ref1> </p>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild("ref1", {read: ElementRef}) ref1: ElementRef;
export function svgLoader( path: string ){
    let graphic = new XMLHttpRequest;

    graphic.open('GET', path, !0),
    graphic.send(),
    graphic.onload = (a)=>{
        let b = document.createElement('div');
        b.setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden');
        b.innerHTML = graphic.responseText;
        this.ref1.nativeElement.insertBefore(b, this.ref1.nativeElement.childNodes[0]);
        //targetObj.insertBefore(b, targetObj.childNodes[0])
    }
}
```

Ref: https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02